# socket.io 'disconnect' event not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

When my node application restarted from command line or restarted by forever.js (if changes detected), then socket.io 'disconnect' event not fired.
My code is as follows :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var session = socket.handshake.session;

    socket.join('room');

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        var clients = io.sockets.clients('room');
        if (!clients || (clients && clients.length === 0)) {
            //remove from online list
        } 
    });
    socket.on('error', function(err) {
        if(err === 'handshake error') { console.log('handshake error', err); } 
        else { console.log('io error', err); }
    });
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        //console.log('messege received on server is "' + data + '"');
    });
});
```

Here my `socket.on('disconnect')` not firing when node.js application is started.
Any guess, why it is not happening/firing?

Comment: Why `disconnect` should be fired when the application is started?

Comment: Have you tried killing completely the process to check if the disconnect event is fired? Usually forever.js restarts the application quiet fast ( depending on the app ), I had a similar problem too.

Comment: ya @David, I have watched after killing process at all. Now I have write following code :  process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
        gracefullyClosing = true;
        //console.log("Received kill signal (SIGTERM), shutting down gracefully.");
        if( io && io.socket ) {
            io.socket.broadcast.send({type: 'error', msg: 'server disconnected with SIGTERM'});
        } });